# Poker with Bluffing (game theory)

Tags: game-theory, board-games

I'm doing a self-study of [Game Theory Evolving by Gintis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691140510), and am stuck on problem 4.16 "Poker with Bluffing".

The first question asks "*Show that Ollie has 64 pure strategies and Stan has 8 pure strategies.*". But no matter how I try to approach this, I can't get more then 4 strategies for Stan!

Here is the game tree for the game in question:
[image]

The question marks (?) in the figure mean that the payoff depends on who has the higher card.

Here is the game description:

- Two players, each with a deck of three cards: H (high), M(medium) or L (low).
- Each puts \$1 in the pot, chooses random card
- Ollie (P1) either stays or raises
- Stan (P2) simultaneously also stays or raises
- If both raise/stay - highest card wins the pot (tie - they take their money back)
- If Ollie raises, Stan stays  Ollie gets the \$3 pot.
- If Stan raises and Ollie stays - Ollie gets another chance:

  -> Drop - Stand wins the \$3 pot

  -> Call - add \$1 to the pot.

Why does Stand have 8 pure strategies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stan has two pure strategies for each type of card. Since there are three types of cards (H, M, L), in total he has $2\times 2\times 2 = 8$ strategies. Here is a list of them:

- Always stay.
- Always raise.
- Stay only if H.
- Stay only if M.
- Stay only if L.
- Raise only if H.
- Raise only if M.
- Raise only if L.

Comment: Ah!!! Thank you. So I could write them down as: `SSS`, `RRR`, `SRR`, `RSR`, `RRS`, `RSS`, `SRS`, `SSR` - where 1nd,2nd and 3rd position are actions for H, M, L cards

Comment: That's correct.